# Mapping relationships in existing database with EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, fluent-interface

I am using an existing database that I am unfortunately unable to change, and seem to be having trouble creating a relationship. I'm relatively new to EF, and after some searches have found users trying to achieve something similar, however the advice given does not seem to work in this situation.

I have the following classes:

```
public partial class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BillingAddressId { get; set; }
    public int ShippingAddressId { get; set; }
    //more values

    public virtual Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
}

public partial class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //more values
}
```

I'd like to be able to access the Shipping/Billing addresses through navigational properties within the order. The `ShippingAddressId`/`BillingAddressId` fields both relate to `Id` in Address class but is unfortunately not set up in the database as a foreign key.

I believe the relationship I'm trying to achieve is many-one. i.e. An Order has one Shipping Address(Address), but an Address can be the Shipping Address of many Orders.

I've tried multiple variations of the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOptional(o => o.ShippingAddress)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(o => o.ShippingAddressId);

}
```

But every time I try to access Order.ShippingAddress.FirstName, I get a null reference exception.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Comment: are you using code first?

Answer (score 1):

If you have disabled lazy loading you will need to 'include' the navigation property in your query

You can do this with one of the following:

```
context.Orders.Include(o=>o.ShippingAddress).Where..... // make sure you are `using System.Data.Entity;`
context.Orders.Include("ShippingAddress").Where.....
```

in addition if your relationship is optional you will need to make the FK id nullable eg:

```
public int? BillingAddressId { get; set; }
public int? ShippingAddressId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm now getting an InvalidOperationException. `A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Model.Order' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'ShippingAddress'`. I may be missing something obvious, but I am sure I have declared it?

Comment: @rmorrin did you change your keys to nullable? From what you have said here you have something a bit wonky in your actually nav property setup. From your above example this is the only issue I can see. Im also assuming you have a similar model bind for billingAddress too